# .net 4 web forms page in debug breaks locally

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, compiler-errors

I'm using visual studio 2010 and .NET 4 and 2 Web Forms.

I have a web forms page that runs perfectly on the web server but if I run it locally I get this error on the page "Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code 1."

On my page I have 9000 lines of JavaScript and I have tried the following:

- If the JavaScript is on the page and in .NET 2 it works perfectly
  locally in debug
- If the JavaScript is in an external file and referenced on the page in
  .NET 4 it works perfectly locally in debug
- If the JavaScript is on the page and in .NET 4 I get the error when
  running locally in bebug
- If I try run it locally and set debug to false in the web config in .NET 4 then it runs perfectly.

*What is wrong here?*

It appears the local visual studio does not the like all the JavaScript on the page in .NET 4 in debug BUT in all cases the site builds and there are no JavaScript errors

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Change some code on the page so that page re-compiles
2. Change something in the web.config so the entire app re-compiles
3. Delete all the files in the "Temporary ASP.Net Files" directory, recompile

These should help with the rather generic error given by the compiler that you tend to get when a reference directive is missing.

Comment: Nope, weird coincidence. Though I have seen that before when I experienced the issue a few months back.